# Print HTML table using crystal reports in Asp.Net

Tags: html, asp.net, crystal-reports, html-table

I am having web application which has one web page. Now I want to print that page using Crystal reports. Web page containing HTML `<Table>` tag. I am new at Asp.net.

i.e.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
          Name :
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
          UserName1
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
          Address :
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
          INDIA
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
</form></html>
```

So can anyone gives some suggestions how to print HTML `<table>` tag in crystal report directly?

Comment: Crystal reports is a tool for generating reports in different formats (HTML/PDF/EXCEL etc). If your *only* requrement is to create an HTML report (and no other formats) using Crystal Reports seems like an overkill. You'd be better off creating a simple aspx page that prints you html using a table control or a repeater control. However, if you *do need* to create the report in crystal you do so by using the crystal reports plugin, which used to ship with previous versions of visual studio but now have to download from SAP. It uses a GUI editor.

Comment: ya thats true, but I read somewhere that Crystal report does not recognize HTML <table> tag. My issue is that how to overcome this problem and print HTML content with table tag using crystal report.